# Wild card character behavior during read stream .meta files?

Tags: azure, pyspark, databricks, spark-streaming, azure-databricks

I am working on real time streaming. When I tried to read all json files which will ends with .json readstream also reads files ending with .json.meta. How can get rid of .meta files.

[image]

In the storage account I have same files one is ending with .json and another one is ending with .json.meta

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I reproduced your code, and i got the files only having extension `.json` as below.

[image]

Below are files I am having.

[image]

So, try restarting your cluster and try.

If you still get this`.json.meta` files, filter out as below.

```
filtered_streaming_df = dfProduc.filter(dfProduc["FileName"].like("%.json"))
```

First, I read all files as below, since i am getting correct json files.

[image]

Then I filtered them.

Output:

[image]

Comment: Hello Thankyou for input however I got new solution to use .option("pathGlobfilter", "*.json") it solved my problem. Thank you for your efforts as well.